# undefined method `image_file_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am struggling trying to figure out why I can't get this helper to function properly. The Item class has a nested reference to a Product class. How can I properly access the "Product" attributes within the helper function below?

```
module ItemHelper

def image_for(item)
   if item.product.image_file_name.blank?
     image_tag('placeholder.png')
   else
     image_tag(item.product.image_file_name)
   end
 end
end
```

I am getting the following error.
"undefined method `image_file_name' for nil:NilClass"
It is happening on the accessing of this image_for function within another html file. I assume it is because I am doing something wrong where I cannot access item.product.

---

The below code is actually functioning code that shows that I have setup what I believe is the correct relationships in the database and models.

```
<ul id="items">
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
<li>
  <article class="item">
    <header>
      <h2><%= item.product.name %></h2>
    </header>
    <p>
      <%= truncate(item.description, length: 150, separator: ' ') %>
    </p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <td><%= item.product.price %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </article>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

Below is the code that I am using to call the helper function.

```
<article id="hint" class="hint">
  <header>
    <%= image_for(@hint) %>
    <h1><%= @hint.name %></h1>
  </header>
  <p>
    <%= @hint.description %>
  </p>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</article>
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: > I cannot access item.product.

You're right. It appears that `product` is returning nil. Are you certain that you have set up the relationships between products and items in your database and models correctly?

Comment: Thanks for replying Dylan. I believe I have this setup properly because I am able to refer to the product object in an index.html.erb just fine.
I added that code above in the original so you can see that.

Comment: Nevertheless, you *definitely* have an `item` with no `product`. This is (based on the code you've posted) the single solitary way this error could occur. You are inadvertently invoking `nil.image_file_name`, and if those are the only places `image_file_name` is being called, then one of those lines has a `item.product` of `nil`.

Comment: I added the code above that is calling the helper method. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Ah. To access variables from the controller in the view, they have to be instance variables (must begin with `@`).

Comment: Go to your ItemsController, find the action that corresponds to the view you're dealing with, and make sure `@item` is set equal to some params (probably `@item = Item.find(params[:id]`). If you're in your index action, `@item = Item.all`

Comment: It turns out that the data for the specific product referenced in the item was nil. So in fact I was chasing down a data issue and not a programming one.
THanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
def image_for(item)
  if item.product.nil? || item.product.image_file_name.blank?
    image_tag('placeholder.png')
  else
    image_tag(item.product.image_file_name)
  end
end
```